# Good Django example/tutorial/book to start with?

Tags: python, django

Does anyone know of a good Django example/tutorial/book for a first hands on?

It would be great if it covered

- session management
- login/authentication
- database connect
- security
- use of html templates

**Update**

Simple examples are really what I am looking for. Something where I start out with the basic functionalities, and can experiment with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com) is a good start.

The book can also be [purchased in print](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597257), if you prefer.

Comment: Also available in print if you prefer that: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1590597257?ie=UTF8&tag=jacobianorg-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=1590597257

Comment: There is a link to that from the site which may get the authors extra money through the amazon affiliate program, that is why I didn't link to it.

Comment: I just checked, it's the same link.

Comment: Except the affiliate getting credit for it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Forgive my ignorance!

Answer (score 2):

When I was just getting started, [Practical Django Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219386) was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Django 1.0 Website Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196780) by Ayman Hourieh from Packt Publishing is a pretty nice place to start as well. The author goes through the entire development process of a social bookmark storage/sharing platform and shows the applications of most of Django's features.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/). It's incredibly detailed and good, and the best resource out there.

Comment: I really don't think that's the *best* place to start though. Their tutorial example thoroughly confused me when I first looked at it without any Django knowledge. I think the docs are the best place to go *after* you've gone through much simpler examples.

Comment: @chands : Simple examples are really what I am looking for. Something where I start out with the basic functionalities, and can experiment with them.

Comment: The documentation is full of examples. I already had a background doing web development, so perhaps that contributed to it, but I found the documentation all I needed to get going, and an invaluable reference going forward. At any rate, one of the best things Django has going for it are it's great docs.

Comment: I don't mean to downplay zeekay's answer as the docs are most definitely going to be your best friend when you're developing. But I do feel that you should use the other two resources pointed out by myself and @Jack M. to start off.

Comment: @zeekay: I can definitely see that. Django was my first foray into Web Development and I was totally lost. That was several months ago, now I love the docs. I really feel it's one of the best set of docs among all the frameworks and languages out there.