# How to display subscript letters in Django forms?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-forms

I have a very naive question. How to display subscripts in the Django form? For example, letters "OC" are the subscripts. 
a. Is there a way to add some arguments in the label section? I have tried `<sub>oc</sub>`, but it was not recognized. 
b. should I try other functions rather than str ?
Thanks for your help!

```
class KabamInp(forms.Form):
    koc = forms.FloatField(label='koc (mL/g OC)')

class InputPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    html=str(kabamInp)
    self.response.out.write(html)
app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', InputPage)], debug=True)
```

Comment: You say say subscript in your question, but you've used the superscript html tag! Doesn't matter though, it's the same answer either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include html tags in your label if you mark the output as safe.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    koc = forms.FloatField(label=mark_safe('koc (mL/g <sub>OC</sub>)'))
```

You should always take care when using `mark_safe`, it can be dangerous when you are dealing with user input. In this case, it should be fine.

Comment: May I know where to add this "mark_safe"? Currently, I am use str function. Does it support html escape?

Comment: koc = forms.FloatField(label=mark_safe('koc (mL/g <sup>OC</sup>)'))

Comment: Oops. Forgetting to include mark_safe wasn't very helpful! I've fixed my answer now.

Comment: @Alasdair. Thanks for your help! In addition, any Django book recommended?

Comment: That's a whole other question! The answers on [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850463/good-django-example-tutorial-book-to-start-with) look sensible.